# pthread_join after pthread_cancel necessary?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, cancellation, pthread-join

I have a multi-threaded program, which each thread runs in a loop if a variable `exit_requested = 0`. Once SIGINT is received by the main thread, the SIGINT handler makes `exit_requested = 1`. Each thread then exits the loop, and the main thread then calls `pthread_cancel()` on each child thread. Is it necessary to then call `pthread_join()` on the child threads?

Comment: The function `pthread_cancel` only sends a cancellation **request**. There is no guarantee that the thread will have finished execution by the time the function returns. Therefore, if your main thread returns from the function `main` without calling `pthread_join` beforehand, you will be killing all remaining threads. Depending on what the threads are doing at the time they get killed, this can lead to data loss and is usually not recommended.

Comment: Taking it one step further, you have a voluntary cleanup mechanism (`exit_requested`) which is being totally bypassed by using `pthread_cancel`. Use one or the other, but not both. Or at least give the thread a chance to notice and honour `exit_requested` before calling `pthread_cancel`.

Comment: Ahh i see, so if i use `exit_requested`, it's better to just `pthread_join()`?

Comment: @doctopus: Yes, that is what I would recommend.